# How do I delete photos in photo albums without using iTunes?

Tags: photos, ipod

I have bought a used iPod which the previous owner had loaded photo albums on. I do not have iTunes and it will not let me delete the photos/photo albums without it.

How do I delete the photo albums that are on this device?

Comment: if it's got someone else's photos on it, it also has their iCloud account. Not a good place to be starting from. Wipe it & hope they removed it from the account from their side, or you'll be stuck with a device you can't use. See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to wipe the iPod (Touch, I assume?). Obviously doing so will **erase all** of those photos, any music, you have on the device, as well as all of your apps.

You [do this](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201274) by going to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Content and Settings.

If it is a new enough device to have iCloud backup, you could always disable photos, before wiping the device, and then restore using the iCloud backup. However, if you have photos on the device that you want saved, this approach will not work.